# Proving a function is an automorphism, but not an inner automorphism

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am solving a homework problem from Benedict Gross's abstract algebra class, the lectures for which are available online. Since there aren't solutions available, I was hoping someone here could look over and critique my solutions. The problem is:

> Define $f: \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R}) \to \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$ by $f(A) = \left(A^t\right)^{-1}$. Show that $f$ is an automorphism, but not an inner automorphism for $n \geq 1$.

Here is my attempt.

> We first show that $f$ is a homomorphism. Given $A,B \in \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$, we have that
> \begin{align*}
> f(AB) = \left[\left(AB\right)^t\right]^{-1} = \left(B^t A^t\right)^{-1} = \left(A^t\right)^{-1} \left(B^t\right)^{-1} = f(A) f(B),
> \end{align*}
> as desired. Second, given $A,B \in \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$ for which $f(A) = f(B)$, we have $\left(A^t\right)^{-1} = \left(B^t\right)^{-1}$, so $A^t = B^t$ since inverses are unique. Transposing both sides, we obtain $A = B$, so $f$ is injective. Finally, given $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$, consider $B = \left(A^{-1}\right)^t$. Since $A$ is invertible, $A^{-1}$ exists and is itself invertible, and since $\det \left(A^{-1}\right) = \det\left(A^{-1}\right)^t$, we have $\left(A^{-1}\right)^t \in \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$. We then have
> \begin{align*}
> f\left(B\right) = \left(B^t\right)^{-1} = \left[\left(\left(A^{-1}\right)^t\right)^t\right]^{-1} = \left(A^{-1}\right)^{-1} = A,
> \end{align*}
> so $f$ is surjective and hence bijective, so $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$. Now suppose for the sake of contradiction that for every $n \geq 1$, $f$ is an inner automorphism, so given such an $n$, there exists a $B \in \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(A) = BAB^{-1}$. But let $\lambda \neq 0,1$ and consider $A = \lambda I$. Since $\lambda \neq 0$, $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$. Furthermore, $\lambda I \in Z\left(\mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})\right) \subset \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> BAB^{-1} = A\left(BB^{-1}\right) = AI = A,
> \end{align*}
> but $f(A) = A^{-1}$, though $A^{-1} \neq A$ since $\frac{1}{\lambda} I \neq I$ for any $\lambda \neq 1$, so we have reached a contradiction.

The way that I derived $A = \lambda I$ is that I was looking for a matrix, generally, for which $A \neq A^{-1}$, i.e., $A^2 \neq I$, and this was the cleanest way to get a counterexample for every natural number $n$. If there are any other counterexamples, I'd be interested in seeing them.

Comment: Your solution has no flaws, well done! Let me remark that your proof mostly works for any field. In fact the result is true for any field except for $\mathbb{F}_2$ (it is easy to see that it fails for $n=1,2$). Thus you had to exclude this case somehow. You achieve this by using the existence of some $\lambda \neq 0,1$.

Comment: For completeness, if the field is $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $n\ge 3$, then this automorphism induces a nontrivial automorphism of the Dynkin diagram and therefore is not inner either. I wonder if there is an easier way to prove this fact.

Comment: The inverse-transpose automorphism maps the stabilizer of a $1$-dimensional subspace to the stabilizer of an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace, so it cannot be inner for $n > 2$.